# Parsing XML in Java to extract all nodes & attributes

Tags: java, xml

I am stuck on an issue trying to parse some XML documents to obtain the output i require.

Take this sample XML:

```html
<root>
      <ZoneRule Name="After" RequiresApproval="false">
         <Zone>
            <WSAZone ConsecutiveDayNumber="1">
               <DaysOfWeek>
                  <WSADaysOfWeek Saturday="false"/>
               </DaysOfWeek>
               <SelectedLimits>
               </SelectedLimits>
               <SelectedHolidays>
               </SelectedHolidays>
            </WSAZone>
         </Zone>
      </ZoneRule>
   <ZoneRule Name="Before" RequiresApproval="false">
         <Zone>
            <WSAZone ConsecutiveDayNumber="3">
               <DaysOfWeek>
                  <WSADaysOfWeek Saturday="true"/>
               </DaysOfWeek>
               <SelectedLimits>
               </SelectedLimits>
               <SelectedHolidays>
               </SelectedHolidays>
            </WSAZone>
         </Zone>
      </ZoneRule>
</root>
```

What i am attempting to do is to be able to ignore the root tag (this is working so no problems here), and treat each of the "ZoneRule's" as its own individual block.

Once i have each ZoneRule isolated i need to extract all of the nodes and attributes to allow me to to create a string to query a database to check if it exists (this part is also working).

The issue i am having is that in my code i cannot separate out each individual ZoneRule block, for some reason it is being processed all as one.

My sample code is as follows:

```html
public String testXML = "";
int andCount = 0;

public void printNote(NodeList nodeList) {

    for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) {

        Node tempNode = nodeList.item(count);

        // make sure it's element node.
        if (tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if (tempNode.hasAttributes()))) {
                // get attributes names and values
                NamedNodeMap nodeMap = tempNode.getAttributes();

                for (int i = 0; i < nodeMap.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nodeMap.item(i);
                    if (andCount == 0) {
                        testXML = testXML + "XMLDataAsXML.exist('//" + tempNode.getNodeName() + "[./@" + node.getNodeName() + "=\"" + node.getNodeValue() + "\"]')=1 \n";
                    } else {
                        testXML = testXML + " and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//" + tempNode.getNodeName() + "[./@" + node.getNodeName() + "=\"" + node.getNodeValue() + "\"]')=1 \n";
                    }
                    andCount = andCount + 1;
                }
            }
            if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                // loop again if has child nodes
                printNote(tempNode.getChildNodes());
            }
        }
    }

}
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Test.xml");
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
            //System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {
                printNote(doc.getChildNodes());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(testXML);

    }
```

Which produces this output (both nodes combined).

```
XMLDataAsXML.exist('//ZoneRule[./@Name="After"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//ZoneRule[./@RequiresApproval="false"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//WSAZone[./@ConsecutiveDayNumber="1"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//WSADaysOfWeek[./@Saturday="false"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//ZoneRule[./@Name="Before"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//ZoneRule[./@RequiresApproval="false"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//WSAZone[./@ConsecutiveDayNumber="3"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//WSADaysOfWeek[./@Saturday="true"]')=1
```

What i am actually after is this (excuse the incomplete SQL statements):

```
XMLDataAsXML.exist('//ZoneRule[./@Name="After"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//ZoneRule[./@RequiresApproval="false"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//WSAZone[./@ConsecutiveDayNumber="1"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//WSADaysOfWeek[./@Saturday="false"]')=1 


XMLDataAsXML.exist XMLDataAsXML.exist('//ZoneRule[./@Name="Before"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//ZoneRule[./@RequiresApproval="false"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//WSAZone[./@ConsecutiveDayNumber="3"]')=1 
 and XMLDataAsXML.exist('//WSADaysOfWeek[./@Saturday="true"]')=1
```

The XML that will be parsed will not always be exactly like above so i cannot use hardcoded xPaths etc - i need to dynamically loop through the document, looking for the ZoneRule node as my base (i will dynamically generate this value based on the file received) and then extract all the required info.

I am completely open to better methods than what i have tried above.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `testXML` and `andCount` are declared outside the `printNote` method and are not being reset during iterations.

You start with the first ZoneRule, generate the correct text during the first for iterations (lets forget about the recursion) and now you move to the next ZoneRule, but testXML contains the whole generated text and the andCount is lager then 0 so you keep attaching the text generated for the next ZoneRule.

You should reset the andCount and testXML at the beggining of each iteriation of the for loop. But then you 'recursive' children would not be rendered correctly.

So either you need two methods one to deal with top level ZoneRule elements and another for its children, or much better, instead of appending to text to shared variable, you should redisng your method so they would return String value which then can be appended correctly (with and or without, withou new line or without) at the place when it is recursively callled.

Comment: Thanks - any samples of some code i could use to achieve this? I have gone around in circles for days....

Comment: copy your printNode method and call it printZone. Inside its for loop at the beginign set andCout=0; testXML=""; leave the rest intact; In your action method, call the printZone instead of the printNode. It should roughly, do the job

Comment: Thanks - i tried your suggestion and sadly i could not get it to make any difference.